# Are a k1 and a 1099-k the same thing

Tags: united-states, taxes

Hi my wife got a K1 for her LLC/S-Corp.  We are currently doing our taxes in Quicken and it's asking if we got a 1099 k. We aren't sure if a 1099 k and a 1099k1 are the same thing.

Comment: K-1 is not a 1099 form, it's a schedule for 1120S or 1065. So she received a 1120S-K1, not a 1099-K1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, they're different. Schedule K-1 is for partnership or pass-through income (associated with Form 1065 for partnerships, Form 1120S for S-Corps, or Form 1041 for estates and trusts), Form 1099-K is for [online payment transactions](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/understanding-your-form-1099-k).

Although she received a K-1, your wife might also receive a 1099-K depending on whether she's required to receive one. For 2022 and prior years, if gross payments exceeded $20,000 AND there were more than 200 transactions. From 2023 onward - if gross payments exceeded $600.

Note: on Dec. 23, 2022, the IRS announced that the implementation of the lower reporting threshold of $600 and any number of transactions, originally scheduled to begin for 2022, is delayed until 2023.

Comment: The rules for 1099-K changed, it is now starting from $600, no matter how many transactions (starting for returns for calendar years after 2021). https://www.irs.gov/businesses/understanding-your-form-1099-k

Comment: This was reversed on December 23, 2022: "NOTE: On Dec. 23, 2022, the IRS announced that calendar year 2022 will be treated as a transition year for the reduced reporting threshold of $600. For calendar year 2022, third-party settlement organizations who issue Forms 1099-K are only required to report transactions where gross payments exceed $20,000 and there are more than 200 transactions."

Comment: I shouldn't say reversed. It was delayed until 2023.

Comment: I read this as "we'll allow the old way of calculating through 2022", not "continue calculating the old way". If the payer uses the new rules - they'd be in the right.

Comment: Correct, payers can adhere to the stricter threshold in 2022 if they wish, but the required threshold has reverted for 2022.

Comment: Nit: K1 can be for 1065 1120S OR 1041. But for this Q only 1120S.

Comment: Ah yes, estate and trust income too, good catch.